# Jenkins ERROR: script returned exit code 4

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, connection

I got a simple Groovy script to install agents on my servers using Ansible.
After I run the pipeline I get error about

> ERROR: script returned exit code 4
> Finished: FAILURE

The error happens because I have two instances not running (I don't want them running) and I get `connection time out` from them.
Is there a way to get Jenkins to ignore such errors?

[image: The pipeline error]

Comment: Please post logs, code or anything the like in code blocks in the body of the question itself, not as print screen. Images should be reserved for thing that are not describable in word. See [ask]

Comment: Please add pipeline code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not-so-ideal solution would be to just state [`ignore_unreachable: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-unreachable-host-errors) at the top of you playbook.

This is no ideal because you risk missing on unreachable hosts you do care about.

A possibly better solution would be to gracefully end those unreachable hosts in a [`meta`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) task based on a list of host(s) you don't need up and running.

For example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost, ok-if-down
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:
    - ping:
      ignore_unreachable: yes
      register: ping

    - meta: end_host
      when:
        - inventory_hostname in _possibly_unreachable_hosts
        - ping is unreachable
      vars:
        _possibly_unreachable_hosts:
          - ok-if-down
          ## add more host(s) name in this list, here

  tasks:
    ## here goes your current tasks
```

When run, the exit code of this playbook would be `0`:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml; echo "Return code is $?"

PLAY [localhost, ok-if-down] **************************************************
TASK [ping] *******************************************************************
fatal: [ok-if-down]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false 
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ok-if-down: Name does not resolve'
  skip_reason: Host ok-if-down is unreachable
  unreachable: true
ok: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *******************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
ok-if-down                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Return code is 0
```